# Does phasing improve imputation quality?

Tags: microarray, wgs, imputation, phasing

If so, by about how much? I want to know the downsides of skipping the phasing step on human microarray and WGS data.

Comment: What method do you want to use - this likely makes a difference.

Comment: @user438383 Beagle/Eagle

Comment: @user438383 but I'd also be interested in other methods if someone happens to know those too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. [Phasing data leads to a better imputation accuracy](https://www.mdpi.com/2075-1729/12/12/2030#B16-life-12-02030). More specifically:

- Improves allele matching: Correct phased data ensures that alleles are matched correctly between the reference panel and the target dataset.
- Using phased data, the computational time of imputation is significantly reduced.
- Having haplotypes (phased data) helps imputing variants that were not genotyped (missing variants/genotypes).

[This paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms9111) based on the UK10K data has some actual numbers describing imputation accuracy of phased vs unphased data.